# Consequences of moving /usr to slower drive

Tags: partitioning, android, performance, android-studio

## Background

I currently have my system all on a very fast nVME PCIe m.2 SSD drive. I want to reinstall everything and I was wondering what some reasonable consequences of moving `/usr` to a fast (but slower) SATA SSD are.

I plan on installing Android Studio, Google Chrome, JetBrain Toolbox along with their IDEs, Java and Gradle as for large additional installations.

## Question

I want Android Studio (Gradle + Java) to be as fast as possible. Right now, I love how fast it is and I am wondering how moving `/usr` to a slower SATA SSD would slow down the feel of Android Studio.

Are most of the important files located in `/home` where it won't affect the speed of Android Studio that much? Or are most important files located in `/usr` where I could expect a slowdown?

I have noticed that Android SDK, Android Studio, and Gradle take up large amounts of disc space over time due to all the newer versions. I am trying to see if I can move stuff to my slower SATA SSD without slowing Android Studio down too much.

**My options appear to be...**

- Leave everything on the nVME SSD to make sure everything is fast, but take up nearly all its space over time due to all the verisions.
- Figure out how to move the import, but non-essential files over to my SATA SSD. I don't know if that is possible

## My Current System

I have 2 partitions on my nVME drive.

#### Partition 1

- `/` = 7.9GB
- `/usr` = 4.5GB
- `/lib` is 917MB
- `/opt` is 591MB

#### Partition 2

- `/home` is 39.7GB

Comment: Right now I plan on wiping clean the whole system and reinstalling Ubuntu 18.04. This will allow me to install the apps as expected and not to my changed locations

Comment: I never used Android studio, but the JetBrains Toolbox installs all IDEs in your home directory (`~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox`)